# Submit Facebook app for approve permissions-Issues

Tags: android, facebook

I submitted my android app to Facebook to review the publish_action permission.But it gives me the following error

**Notes from our review team
Android
Unfortunately we cannot install your app onto our test device. We are reviewing your app on an HTC First, Android version 4.1.2. Also, even when an application is under development, developers can configure a test user that has granted tokens for the publish_actions permission. Please resubmit a test app with a test user and detailed reproduction steps for us to review your app further**

But i can install my app on HTC Vivid Android 4.0.3 and higher version(4.1.2,4.4.2).
Please give me the guidelines solution for my submission issues

Comment: your facebook app is live? your hashkey is for production or test?

Comment: My facebook app is not in live

Comment: @kalai did you solved the proble,

Comment: On average, how long it takes to review the app